# Как правильно именовать классы в C++?

Tags: c++, qt, solid

Следую правилам SOLID, а конкретнее правилу единой ответственности. Есть у меня класс, отвечающий за чтение файлов по пути "Reading" (перебираем файлы, папки и тд). И мне допустим нужно перебирать изображения, надо ли удалить класс "Reading" и разбить его на классы "ReadingFiles", "ReadingFolders" и "ReadingImage" ? По факту класс "Reading" у меня и так занимался одним делом, то есть считывал данные(и файлы, и картинки и папки).

Comment: ну зачем удалять, можно сделать класс Reading базовым, а ReadingFiles/Folders ... пронаследовать от него

Comment: Не думаю, лучше просто назвать экземпляры выбранными именами или определить  псевдоним типа или см. коммент выше.

Comment: Вы по моему напрасно концентрируетесь на вводе/выводе, он в силу своей простоты обычно раскидан по более умным классам, см. например `QImage::load(QIODevice *device, const char *format)`